# Attach debugger on android device monitor with Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-debug

I'm using Android studio 1.2. 
I can attach the debugger from android studio internally. but when I open the Android device monitor the 'debugger' button is disabled and I can't attach the debugger to a process from that window. In fact I need to close the Android Device Monitor to be able to attach the debugger directly from android studio (Android debugger tab).

Any idea to attach the debugger directly from Android Device Monitor ? 
thanks

Comment: Could you post some screenshots of what you mean to clarify?

Comment: I can't :( . I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I just want to be able to attach the debugger from Android device Monitor, Like I do before with Eclipse.

Comment: is there a solution to this problem yet?